# Angular material md-chips autocomplete incorrect rendering

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm currently working with Angular-material.
What I'm trying to achieve is a input field with md-chips and autocomplete.

The problem that i'm having is that the "dropdown" with the suggestions doesn't render correctly. As in the last 2 items in the list don't render, as shown below.

[image: actual]

And if I scroll all the way down it shows Test4/Test5/Test6, but not Test7 & Test8 (The list contains 8 items).
If I look in the dom I notice that there are no dom elements for the last 2 items.

The html code that I used is:

```
<md-chips ng-model="result" md-autocomplete-snap>
    <md-autocomplete
        md-autofocus="false"
        md-min-length="0"
        md-search-text="searchText"
        md-items="item in items"
        placeholder="Filter">
        <md-item-template>{{item}}</md-item-template>
    </md-autocomplete>
    <md-chip-template><span><em>{{$chip}}</em></span></md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

I have a simple [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Btdx6m8rYVOp1uPQYtHj?p=preview) in which you can see how it works.

**How can I make the dropdown render correctly?**

*Edit:*

I've noticed that if the dropdown is open and the window resizes the dropdown re-renders correctly

Comment: Haven't looked into why, but seems to work with version 0.11.4.

Comment: Ive tried it out, it seems to be working in the plunker when I change te version to 0.11.4. Sadly that doesn't fix it for the interface I'm working on currently.

Comment: have you managed to fix it ?